# Karma with Jasmine and Rails javascript manifest

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to add Karma to a Rails app that uses Jasmine for javascript tests. The app has a complex manifest files that I would like to leverage in my Karma config.

Can I use my manifest file (or the resulting output) in my Karma config somehow so I don't need to duplicate the list of Javascript vendor libraries and my classes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcards in karma config to include javascript vendor and app files:

```
files: [
    'vendor/assets/**/*.js',
    'app/assets/**/*.js',
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leverage your `//= require` declaration in your `application.js`, you need to use Karma in the context of Sprockets (the assets pipeline). For that you need a special rake task which will run this code:

```
sprockets = Rails.application.assets
sprockets.append_path Rails.root.join("spec/karma")
files = Rails.application.assets.find_asset("application_spec.js").to_a.map {|e| e.pathname.to_s }
```

If you want complete guide, I wrote an [article](http://sebastien.saunier.me/blog/2014/02/04/angular--rails-with-no-fuss.html).